# Mucked up disablement of Notifications Center

Tags: macos, command-line, notifications

Tried to disable Notifications Center and remove it from the menu bar, unfortunately didn't copy the whole command:

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents
```

Now I'm presented with a completely black screen when I login, and

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents
```

doesn't seem to help. What should I do now?

[Rebuilding the user account](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-rebuild-a-user-account-in-os-x/) didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [launchtl man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html), it looks like it might need the -F parameter to force loading.

`launchctl load -wF /System/Library/LaunchAgents`

I can't tell if it needs `sudo` too, though it might, as the LaunchAgents folder is `root:wheel rwxr-xr-x`